# How to install (or fake) ssl on EasyPhp local dev for deving secure sites

Tags: ssl, easyphp

I'm deving locally, Win vista, EasyPHP 5.3.9.  I have a site that redirects to https for the shopping cart.  So I need to install a ssl cert in my local version of the site: thedomain.local.  It doesnt have to be real or anything, and I dont mind adding an exception if my browser complains.  I just want the site to run as if ssl were installed here as it is on the real server.

Comment: You could just change all links to be compatible with both SSL and non-SSL. I.e. `<a href="//google.com">google</a>` will go to `https://google.com` if you're on a SSL connection.

Comment: No, it's not that.  The cart checks to see if youre on https when you hit a checkout page and redirects to https if not.